# Is it possible to avoid div wrapper when I use HtmlCommand or ReplaceCommand?

Tags: 8, ajax

I'm working on a D8 project and I have some ajax callbacks where I use `ReplaceCommand` and `HtmlCommand`.

It works fine but adds an extra div to my html.

For example I do :

```
$response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('select[name="field_expert_name"]', $options));
```

And in my select, instead of getting just the options, I get :

```
<select>
  <div style="display: block;">
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
  </div>
</select>
```

Is is possible to get rid of this extra div?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/736066. But why not replace the complete form element? Which is btw. necessary for other reasons too. When you want to submit the form without errors, include the select in the form build/alter. Then you can send the processed select element in an ajax callback.

Comment: No, this is a known issue that is nowhere near fixing. you just have to use wrapper with some random id and then unwrap it.

Comment: Thank you both for the response. @4k4 the field I try to alter doesn't belong to this form. I'm returning the form element in other cases!